# Spring RabbitMQ: why does client NOT auto-recover after network outage?

Tags: rabbitmq, spring-rabbit

Versions:

```
org.springframework.amqp:spring-rabbit:2.4.7
openjdk version "11.0.12" 2021-07-20
```

As mentioned in several other articles, including:

- https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-amqp/issues/823
- [Rabbitmq client loosing connection and does not recover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69108827/rabbitmq-client-loosing-connection-and-does-not-recover)

RabbitMQ client at times will drop its connection to the broker and never auto-recover.

As explained in [Spring AMQP documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/reference/html/amqp.html#connection-factory), auto-recovery is encoded in the AMQP client.  In my client setup, I use `SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory`, and per recommendation in said documentation, I neither set `automaticRecoveryEnabled` nor `topologyRecoveryEnabled`.

Logs show this exception:

```
[AMQP Connection 35.82.255.136:5671] ERROR com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ForgivingExceptionHandler - An unexpected connection driver error occurred
com.rabbitmq.client.MissedHeartbeatException: Heartbeat missing with heartbeat = 60 seconds at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection.handleSocketTimeout(AMQConnection.java:847) ~[amqp-client-5.13.1.jar:5.13.1]
        at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection.readFrame(AMQConnection.java:747) [amqp-client-5.13.1.jar:5.13.1]
        at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection.access$300(AMQConnection.java:47) [amqp-client-5.13.1.jar:5.13.1]
        at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection$MainLoop.run(AMQConnection.java:666) [amqp-client-5.13.1.jar:5.13.1]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829) [?:?]
```

After this exception happened, there is NO auto-recovery; moreover, the logs do not reference RabbitMQ client again until I restart the containing service.

XML configuration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans profile="staging,prod"
  xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
  xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
  xmlns:rabbit="http://www.springframework.org/schema/rabbit"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
           https://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/rabbit
           https://www.springframework.org/schema/rabbit/spring-rabbit.xsd">

  <rabbit:annotation-driven/>

  <!-- Scan for components with @RabbitListener. -->
  <context:component-scan base-package="com.predicine.ingress.tasks">
    <context:include-filter type="regex" expression="com.acme.tasks.ConsumeBarcodes"/>
  </context:component-scan>

  <rabbit:connection-factory id="connectionFactory" connection-factory="clientConnectionFactory"/>

  <bean id="clientConnectionFactory" class="org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.RabbitConnectionFactoryBean">
    <property name="username" value="${rabbitmq.user}" />
    <property name="password" value="${rabbitmq.password}" />
    <property name="host" value="${rabbitmq.host}" />
    <property name="port" value="${rabbitmq.port}" />
    <property name="useSSL" value="true" />
    <property name="keyStore" value="classpath:/keycert.jks" />
    <property name="keyStorePassphrase" value="changeit" />
    <property name="keyStoreType" value="PKCS12" />
    <property name="trustStore" value="classpath:/trustStore" />
    <property name="trustStorePassphrase" value="changeit" />
    <property name="trustStoreType" value="PKCS12" />
  </bean>

  <rabbit:admin connection-factory="connectionFactory"/>

  <rabbit:queue name="${rabbitmq.queue}" durable="true" auto-delete="false">
    <rabbit:queue-arguments>
      <!-- Let messages sit up to 48 hours in queue. Presumably within that timeframe we can bring our consumers back online. -->
      <entry key="x-message-ttl" value="172800000" value-type="java.lang.Integer"/>
    </rabbit:queue-arguments>
  </rabbit:queue>

  <rabbit:fanout-exchange name="${rabbitmq.exchange}" durable="true" auto-delete="false">
    <rabbit:bindings>
      <rabbit:binding queue="${rabbitmq.queue}" />
    </rabbit:bindings>
  </rabbit:fanout-exchange>

  <bean id="rmqMessageConverter" class="org.springframework.amqp.support.converter.Jackson2JsonMessageConverter">
    <constructor-arg ref="myObjectMapper"/>
  </bean>

  <bean id="rabbitListenerContainerFactory" class="org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.config.SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory">
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="connectionFactory"/>
    <property name="concurrentConsumers" value="1"/>
    <property name="maxConcurrentConsumers" value="1"/>
    <property name="receiveTimeout" value="316224000000"/>
    <property name="messageConverter" ref="rmqMessageConverter"/>
  </bean>
</beans>
```

Java:

```
package com.acme.tasks;

import com.acme.io.NewBarcodes;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.annotation.RabbitListener;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.validation.annotation.Validated;

@Validated
@Component
public class ConsumeBarcodes
{
  private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ConsumeBarcodes.class);

  @Value("${rabbitmq.queue}")
  private String queueName;

  public ConsumeBarcodes() {}

  @RabbitListener(queues = "${rabbitmq.queue}", ackMode = "AUTO")
  public void ingestNewBarcodes(@NotNull NewBarcodes newBarcodes)
  {
    logger.debug("RECEIVED message in ingestNewBarcodes from RabbitMQ queue: {}", queueName);
    // XXX Process newBarcodes here.
  }
}
```

QUESTIONS:

- Why isn't auto-recovery working?
- Should I enable `automaticRecoveryEnabled` and `topologyRecoveryEnabled` in `SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory`?
- In this setup, how can I encode the consumer-handler `handleShutdownSignal`?

Comment: No; auto recovery is not compatible; if it is set, it will effectively be disabled anyway. The listener container will automatically recover itself; please show logs (debug if possible) if that is not happening.

Comment: @GaryRussell:  I confirmed auto-recovery logic (in listener container) works on network reset.  However, the original issue triggered under slightly different circumstances; so I am suspicious there is a bug lurking inside the Spring RabbitMQ client.  I am not sure about the precise networking alterations that resulted in our RabbitMQ client going offline; I believe alterations were more than just toggling the network interface (to the RabbitMQ broker) on / off.

Comment: I am not that familiar with the `amqp-client`'s internals, but it looks to me that 2 missed heartbeats will throw that exception and shut down the connection, which will trigger reconnection. You could try upgrading the amqp-client jar from 5.13.1 (pulled in by spring-rabbit 2.4.x); the latest is currently 5.16.0; the latest spring-amqp 2.4.x is 2.4.8.

Comment: @GaryRussell: so I should `connectionFactory.setRequestedHeartBeat(60);`
and will it work?

Comment: @袁文涛:  if there is a network outage, the duration of the heartbeat will not impact recovery at all.  Shortening the duration just means you trigger the exception on average sooner rather than later; lengthening the duration means the opposite.  I believe there is a bug lurking in spring-amqp client, but you should install a recent version to be sure.

Comment: @Gary Russell What if I am not using listenerContainer, How can I enable auto-recover after network outage?